# How to format X-axis and Y-axis properly in pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots

Here is my code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=2016, xmax=2023,
        ymin=6000, ymax=10000
    ]
        \addplot[smooth,mark=*,blue] plot coordinates {
            (2016, 7400)
            (2017, 7580)
            (2018, 7830)
            (2019, 7910)
            (2020, 7640)
            (2021, 8560)
            (2022, 8510)
            (2023, 7440)
        };
        \addlegendentry{Trend}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The result graph looks like this:

[image]

I would like to show X-axis as year (no thousand separator) and Y-axis showing the numbers, instead of something like 0.6 x10<sup>4</sup>. What did I miss?

Comment: Can you please add the missing lines so your snippet will compile when we copy and try it? It also avoids guessworking on your preamble. And yes, this can already be tricky here. Good code results in good answers more often than not. Thank you

Comment: The axis are already formatted properly. The formatting of axis depends on use case and preferences/customs of the author. -so suggesting that it is not properly is bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=2016, xmax=2023,
ymin=6000, ymax=10000,
/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={},
scaled y ticks=false,
]
\addplot[blue, smooth, mark=*] plot coordinates {
(2016, 7400)
(2017, 7580)
(2018, 7830)
(2019, 7910)
(2020, 7640)
(2021, 8560)
(2022, 8510)
(2023, 7440)
};
\addlegendentry{Trend}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with x scale in years]